# Creating a custom ManagedContentType in a SFDX Project

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api

I'm trying to understand the best place in my SFDX project to place the file for a custom ManagedContentType.   I tried to place this file in the location `force-app\main\default\managedContentTypes/blog.managedContentType` based on output from the command `sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m ManagedContentType` which outputs:

```
{ createdById: '0053D0000XXXXXX',
  createdByName: 'User User',
  createdDate: '2020-02-11T19:39:52.000Z',
  fileName: 'managedContentTypes/news.managedContentType',
  fullName: 'news',
  id: '0T13D000XXXXXXXX',
  lastModifiedById: '0053D000XXXXXX',
  lastModifiedByName: 'User User',
  lastModifiedDate: '2020-02-11T19:39:52.000Z',
  type: 'ManagedContentType' }
```

Is there a better location to place these XML files to define custom ManagedContentType records?

Docs Reference:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_managedcontenttype.htm

Update: I found the following post describing how to create content types with the Tooling API https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/11/use-the-cms-app-to-create-content.html